# Removing line from html table using CSS

Tags: html, css

My page has several tables on it, and before each table, a line is showing.  I don't want that line.

Here is an example:
HTML:

```
echo '<h4>Posting Information</h4>';
        echo '<table class="showApp">
            <tbody><tr>';
                echo sprintf('<td><label>Location: </label>%s</td>',$posting['LocationName']);
                echo sprintf('<td><label>Created: </label>%s</td>',$posting['ApplicantPostingCreated']);
                echo sprintf('<td><label>Department: </label>%s</td>',$posting['DepartmentName']);
                echo sprintf('<td><label>Position: </label>%s</td>',$posting['PositionName']);
            echo '</tr></tbody>
        </table>';
```

CSS:

```
.showApp td, .showApp tr, .showApp th, .showApp {
border: 0px;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 0px;
}
```

And it displays:
[image: table]

How do I get rid of that line?

Comment: Can you post a JSfiddle? I created one but it doesn't reproduce your issue so yo must have other stuff going on there. Here's mine: http://jsfiddle.net/bhuqeax0/

Comment: You should be able to right click, "inspect element", and see what is causing the line.  Could it be the h4?

Comment: have you tried: table{ border: none; } ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what worked is this:

```
table.showApp tbody tr td { border: 0px; }
```